# How to return outer html of DOMDocument?

Tags: php, dom, outerhtml

I'm trying to replace video links inside a string - here's my code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("a") as $link) 
{
    $url = $link->getAttribute("href");
    if(strpos($url, ".flv"))
    {
        echo $link->outerHTML();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `outerHTML` doesn't work when I'm trying to get the html code for the full hyperlink like `<a href='http://www.myurl.com/video.flv'></a>`

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 23):

As of PHP 5.3.6 you can pass a node to `saveHtml`, e.g.

```
$domDocument->saveHtml($nodeToGetTheOuterHtmlFrom);
```

Previous versions of PHP did not implement that possibility. You'd have to use `saveXml()`, but that would create XML compliant markup. In the case of an `<a>` element, that shouldn't be an issue though.

See http://blog.gordon-oheim.biz/2011-03-17-The-DOM-Goodie-in-PHP-5.3.6/

Comment: The DOMNode also contains the containing DOMDocument so you can do this if you just have the node you want to get the HTML of: 
$domNode->ownerDocument->saveHTML($domNode);

Answer (score 6):

You can find a couple of propositions in the users notes of the [**DOM section**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) of the PHP Manual.

For example, here's one posted by [**xwisdom**](http://xwisdom) :

```
<?php
// code taken from the Raxan PDI framework
// returns the html content of an element
protected function nodeContent($n, $outer=false) {
    $d = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $b = $d->importNode($n->cloneNode(true),true);
    $d->appendChild($b); $h = $d->saveHTML();
    // remove outter tags
    if (!$outer) $h = substr($h,strpos($h,'>')+1,-(strlen($n->nodeName)+4));
    return $h;
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for that but i'm actually looking for the full OUTER html - the full code including <a href ...></a> :/

Comment: @Fuxi judging by the code I'd say you have to set $outer to TRUE then. But there is really no reason to use that function, because you can use `saveXml` and `saveHTML` to get the outerHTML like explained in my answer.

Comment: @Gordon thanks for your comment :-)  *(And I agree with the "use saveHTML" idea -- if using PHP >= 5.3.6)*

Answer (score 5):

The best possible solution is to define your own function which will return you outerhtml:

```
function outerHTML($e) {
     $doc = new DOMDocument();
     $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($e, true));
     return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

than you can use in your code

```
echo outerHTML($link);
```

Comment: Only for PHP < 5.3.6, after that just provide the node as argument for saveHTML(), like Gordon wrote. No need to create an full document, just to save a single node.

Answer (score 0):

Rename a file with href to links.html or links.html to say google.com/fly.html that has flv in it or change flv to wmv etc you want href from if there are other href 
it will pick them up as well

```
  <?php
  $contents = file_get_contents("links.html");
  $domdoc = new DOMDocument();
  $domdoc->preservewhitespaces=“false”;
  $domdoc->loadHTML($contents);
  $xpath = new DOMXpath($domdoc);
  $query = '//@href';
  $nodeList = $xpath->query($query);
  foreach ($nodeList as $node){
    if(strpos($node->nodeValue, ".flv")){
      $linksList = $node->nodeValue;
      $htmlAnchor = new DOMElement("a", $linksList);
      $htmlURL = new DOMAttr("href", $linksList);
      $domdoc->appendChild($htmlAnchor);
      $htmlAnchor->appendChild($htmlURL);
      $domdoc->saveHTML();
      echo ("<a href='". $node->nodeValue. "'>". $node->nodeValue. "</a><br />");
    }
  }
echo("done");
?>
```