# php DOMDocument: complete transform of form element? wrapping and removing?

Tags: php, domdocument, word-wrap

hey guys,
`$form` holds this...

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="127.0.0.1">
    <label for="s2email">Your Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="s2email" value="email..." size="20" onfocus="if (this.value == 'email...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'email...';}">
    <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe">
    <input type="submit" name="unsubscribe" value="Unsubscribe">
</form>
```

Since I have no idea what's possible with the `DOMDocument` class I need to ask for help.
I actually have two things I need to transform on the $form above.

1.) `label-s2email and its input#sd-email` should be wrapped inside a `<div class="name">`
Is that even possible to select those two (via id or for-attribute) and wrap those two into a div?

2.) Is it possible to remove the onfocus and onblur attribute with php?

thank you for your help

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) and [Noob Question about `DOMDocument` in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I cannot find a suitable duplicate that shows how to wrap nodes with `DOM`, here is the solution:

```
// Setup DOMDocument and XPath
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($form);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Create <DIV> with class attribute name
$div = $dom->createElement('div');
$div->setAttribute('class', 'name');

// Find <input id="s2email"> and remove event attributes
$input = $xpath->query('/html/body/form/input[@id="s2email"]')->item(0);
$input->removeAttribute('onfocus');
$input->removeAttribute('onblur');

// Find <label for="s2email"> and insert new DIV before that
$label = $xpath->query('/html/body/form/label[@for="s2email"]')->item(0);
$label->parentNode->insertBefore($div, $label);

// Move <label> and <input> into the new <div>
$div->appendChild($label);
$div->appendChild($input);

// Echo the <form> outer HTML
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('form')->item(0));
```

The above code will produce ([live demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RiUMq5)):

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="127.0.0.1"><div class="name">
<label for="s2email">Your Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="s2email" value="email..." size="20">
</div>
    <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe"><input type="submit" name="unsubscribe" value="Unsubscribe">
</form>
```

Note that in order to pass a node to `saveHTML`, you need PHP 5.3.6. See

- http://gooh.posterous.com/the-dom-goodie-in-php-536
- [How to return outer html of DOMDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element)

for possible workarounds before that.

Comment: exactly the thing I want to do, perfect. I made it work with saveXML.

Comment: Is there any chance I could query if the form even exists? Because once the form i submitted the page reloads and there is no form. In this case my console throws errors because all those operations on the form can not be done and nothing's found.

Comment: well, the easiest would be to use `strpos` and check if $form contains "<form" before loading it with DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The lazy solution would be to use phpQuery or [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) which allow for:

```
print qp($html)
   ->find("*[onfocus], *[onblur]")->removeAttr("onblur")->removeAttr("onfocus")
   ->top()->find("label[for=s2email], input#s2email")->wrapAll("<div class='name'></div>")
   ->top("form")->xml();
```

Albeit in this case you could use DOMDocument directly. Only the wrapping part would be a bit more elaborate there. You could simpify this if you wrapped the `<label>` around the `<input>` instead of using a `for=` and `name=` relationship.