# php DOMDocument adds <html> headers with DOCTYPE declaration

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm adding a #b hash to each link via the DOMDocument class.

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($output);

        $a_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

        foreach($a_tags as $a)
        {
            $value = $a->getAttribute('href');
            $a->setAttribute('href', $value . '#b');
        }

        return $dom->saveHTML();
```

That works fine, however the returned output includes a `DOCTYPE` declaration and a `<head>` and `<body>` tag. Any idea why that happens or how I can prevent that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP + DOMDocument: outerHTML for element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to saveHTML of DOMDocument without HTML wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what [**`DOMDocument::saveHTML()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) generally does, yes : generate a full HTML Document, with the Doctype declaration, the `<head>` tag, ...

Two possible solutions :

- If you are working with PHP >= 5.3, `saveHTML()` accepts one additional parameter that might help you

  - see [**The DOM Goodie in PHP 5.3.6**](http://gooh.posterous.com/the-dom-goodie-in-php-536) for more informations.
- If you need your code to work with PHP < 5.3.6, you'll have to use some `str_replace()` or regex or whatever equivalent you can think of to remove the portions of HTML code you don't need.

  - For an example, see [**this note**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php#85165) in the manual's users notes.

Comment: the second link works fine for me - preg_replace solution is the key! thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :-) *(and the guys who post users notes on manual pages are more to be thanked than me, in this case ;-) )*

Comment: I used the first option as I am using PHP >= 5.3 and it worked great. `$doc->saveHTML(false);`

Comment: @BenSinclair I am also using PHP >= 5.3 and `$doc->saveHTML(false)` throws the error `<b>Warning</b>:  DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects parameter 1 to be DOMNode, boolean given`

Answer (score 6):

The real problem is the way the DOM is loaded. Use this instead:

```
$html->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Please upvote the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/2546416).

Answer (score 2):

Adding `$doc->saveHTML(false);` will not work and it will return a error because it expects a node and not bool.

The solution I used:

`return preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $doc->saveHTML()));`

I`m using PHP >5.4

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating new DOMDocument and copying child nodes from original to new one.

```
function removeDocType($oldDom) {
  $node = $oldDom->documentElement->firstChild
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  foreach ($node->childNodes as $child) {
    $dom->appendChild($doc->importNode($child, true));
  }
  return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

So insted of using

```
return $dom->saveHTML();
```

I use:

```
return removeDocType($dom);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the case where I want the html wrapper but not the DOCTYPE, the solution was in line with Tiago A.:

```
// Avoid adding the DOCTYPE header    
$dom->loadHTML($bodyContent, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

// Avoid adding the DOCTYPE header AND html/body wrapper
$dom->loadHTML($bodyContent, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```