# DomDocument Not Saving

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I wrote this function but it doesn't seem to be saving the `$dom`.  If I check the attribute after I set it, it is correct, but it just doesn't make it to the final save.

```
function tj_add_alts( $content ) {
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName( 'img' ) as $node) {
    if ( trim( $node->getAttribute( 'alt' ) ) == "" ) {
        $img = $node->getAttribute( 'src' );
        $file_name = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $name = preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', ' ', $file_name);
        $name = preg_replace( '/\s{2,}/', ' ', $name);
        $node->setAttribute( 'alt', $name );
    }
}

$content = $dom->saveHTML();

return $content;
}
```

UPDATE: It looks like the problem is that DomDocument automatically adds the `doctype` declaration and `<body>` and `<head>` tags, which I don't want.  Is there a way to get ride of those?

Comment: [DOMDocument::saveHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)'s 2nd argument allows you to output a subset of the document, just use it to get the HTML portion you want. If you add an example of your HTML we might come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the following through your function to test it:

```
$content = <<<EOTAAA
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Image:</h1>
<img src="images/betsy.jpg" alt="Betsy eating an apple"/>
<img src="images/doug.jpg" alt=""/>
</body>
</html>

EOTAAA;
```

Then I echoed the value of `$content` which was returned from the function. The result was that your function works great. Nothing happed with the image tag for `betsy.jpg` because the function only modifies the HTML when it finds an empty `alt` attribute. However the image tag for `doug.jpg` was as follows:

```
<img src="images/doug.jpg" alt="doug">
```

I'm guessing that's exactly what you want it to do, so if there's a problem, it has nothing to do with the code you posted.

Comment: I have found where the problem is. domdocument automatically adds the `doctype` declaration and `html and body` tags.  Do you know of a way to suppress that?

Comment: That issue was brought up in another SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444510/php-domdocument-adds-html-headers-with-doctype-declaration. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use the `saveHTMLFile` method?

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php

Comment: No I don't want to save it to a file.  I just want to save it to a string.

Comment: Gotchya; getting any errors?

Comment: Also, have you dumped all values in your `if()` statement with `var_dump` to ensure they're all set?

Comment: Nope, no errors. And yes I have, it properly executes, and I can actually check at the end right after I set the attribute with `$node->getAttribute( 'alt' );` and it is the correct value.