# printing out html content from domelement using nodeValue

Tags: php

I have image in html. I parse it to DOMDocument and start working with it...

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
$container = $img->parentNode;

if ($container->tagName != "a") { 
    $image_inside=utf8_decode($img->nodeValue);
    echo "3".$image_inside;
    die;
}
}
```

This code works fine line 3 gets image. line 6 understands that there is no "a" tag above this "img" tag, and line 8 must print out my initial image. But the thing is I only see "3" without image tag and etc...

I did inspect element and nothing is there. just "3" is coming out. Why I cannot print out image ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP + DOMDocument: outerHTML for element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
DOMDocument::saveXML($img);
```

From PHP Documetation's [saveXML()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php).

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($article_header);

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $container = $img->parentNode;

    if ($container->tagName != "a") { 
       echo utf8_decode($doc->saveXML($img));
       die;
    }
}
```

If you're using PHP 5.3.6 you could use (from [How to return outer html of DOMDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element))

```
$doc->saveHtml($img);
```

Note the caveat mentioned in the linked-to question:

> (...) use saveXml(), but that would
>   create XML compliant markup. In the
>   case of an `<a>(<img>)` element, that shouldn't
>   be an issue though.

Comment: most probably you want me to get source from that image tag, but what I want is to get back the whole "img" tags html. THat's why I'm trying to use ->nodeValue but nothing happens

Comment: @ Michael Sorry i'm a noobie in such questions, can you modify my example so the image will print out ?