# How to debug or print a DOMDocument object in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, object, domdocument

I'm trying to print the value (content) of the variable `$this->XMLNominaCFDI`

```
$XMLCFDI->normalizeDocument();

$this->XMLNominaCFDI = $XMLCFDI->saveXML();
```

I've been looking for here on SO but this answers didn't help me

[Debug a DOMDocument Object in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684227/debug-a-domdocument-object-in-php)

[printing out html content from domelement using nodeValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6321481/printing-out-html-content-from-domelement-using-nodevalue)

when I use `var_dump` it shows this `string(2202) " "`

How could I display the content of see the xml tree till this moment?

I hope you can help me, thanks.

PSD: I'm using PHP 5.2.17

Comment: @RobertWade `print_r` show nothing

Comment: Use your browser's *view source code* function if you are outputting the result to a browser, as a browser will interpret the result as XML. Or use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to translate the XML to an in-browser-readable format.

Comment: @DecentDabbler Im generating the xml first to pass it as a parameter to a function but before send it I want to see how it looks like but it is not working, I tried `htmlentities()` as you said but nothing

Comment: Are you viewing the output in a browser? If so, have you tried: `$this->XMLNominaCFDI =  $XMLCFDI->saveXML(); var_dump( htmlentities( $this->XMLNominaCFDI ) );`?

Comment: Oh yes now it is working I was trying this way `echo htmlentities($this->XMLNominaCFDI)` but now as you said it is working very well, this is what i wanted, thank you!