# How to get tag content using DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

Say this is the HTML?

```
<html>
<body>
<embed scr="...." attr="..."></embed>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to match whole embed tag `<embed scr="...." attr="..."></embed>`. How can I do so?

I got this far

```
$fragment = new DOMDocument();
$fragment->loadHTML($string);

$xp = new DOMXPath($fragment);
$result = $xp->query("//embed");
print_r($result->item(0));
```

Comment: You cannot dump DOMElement's or any other of the DOM objects. Pass the node to saveXML or saveHTML to get the outerHTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP + DOMDocument: outerHTML for element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
<?php
$fragment = new DOMDocument();
$fragment->loadHTML($string);

foreach ($fragment->getElementsByTagName("embed") as $element) 
{
    echo $fragment->saveXML($element);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at this [PHP Class](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

If I understood your problem correctly. Doing it with this class would be as simple as:

```
$html = str_get_html($string);
$ret = $html->find('embed');
```

EDIT. And the same thing in [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/):

```
phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($string);
$ret = pq('embed');
```

You should look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php/3577662#3577662) of Gordon by the way.

Comment: Was just reading it and updating my answer for future references. Beat me to it ;-)