# DOMDocument and php html problems

Tags: php, dom

Alright. So I'm using DOMDocument to read html files. One thing I've noticed is that when I do  this

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlstring);
$doc->saveHTML();
```

it will add on a doctype header, and html and body tags.

I've gotten around this by doing this

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($htmlstring,LIBXML_NOXMLDECL);
$doc->saveXML();
```

The problem with this however is the fact that now all my tags are case sensitive, and it gets mad if I have more than one document root.

Is there an alternative so that I can load up partial html files, grab tags and such, replace them, and get the string without having to parse the files manually?

Basically I want the functionallity of `DOMDocument->loadHTML`, without the added tags and header.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could tell libxml not to add the implied markup. In practise, PHP's libxml bindings do not provide any means to that. If you are on PHP 5.3.6+ pass the root node of your partial document to `saveHTML()`which will then give you the outerHTML of that element, e.g.

```
$dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0));
```

would only return the `<body>` element with children. See

- [How to return outer html of DOMDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element)

Also note that your partial document with multiple root elements only works *because* `loadHTML` adds the implied elements. If you want a partial with multiple roots (or rather no root at all) back, you can add a fake root yourself:

```
$dom->loadHTML('<div id="partialroot">' . $partialDoc . '</div>');
```

Then process the document as needed and then fetch the innerHTML of that fake root

- [How to get innerHTML of DOMNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)

Also see [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) for additional parsers you might want to try

Answer (score 0):

You can use some divs with specific id, and then from the document object, partially extract the div object using its id.