# extract all css styles from html (excluding the ones wrapped in conditional comments)

Tags: php, html, css

I need a regex to extract all the stylesheets (`<link>` tags) from a html document.

Currently i have `preg_match_all('/<link([^>]*?)>/i',...`, and that regex extracts the stylesheets... that's fine.

But, I need to exclude the styles wrapped in IEs conditional tags `<!--[if IE...]>bla bla<![endif]-->`...

Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: Here is a tip. Don't use regex.

Comment: great tip.. wish I couldmark it as accepted ;)

Comment: Just add a negative lookbehind to your regex. But this doesn't guarantee what happens with nested elements etc. You have been warned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use DOM and XPath for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$stylesheets = $xpath->query('/html/head/link[@rel="stylesheet"]');
foreach ($stylesheets as $stylesheet) {
    echo $dom->saveHtml($stylesheet);
}
```

This will only print the stylesheets in the head element excluding those inside comment nodes. And if you need to limit that even further, for instance by media attribute then simply add that as another condition to the Xpath query.

In case saveHTML doesnt accept a node in your version of PHP see

- [How to return outer html of DOMDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element)