# RegEx: Keep HTML tags, remove only html specialchars

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a regex to remove all html special chars (mostly &, <, >) but keeping the html tags intact.

I'm getting these informations from a database, so I can't make sure that characters like < and > are replaced with &gt; and &lt;

I could manage to replace & and < it with the following RegEx in PHP:

```
$Value = preg_replace('/<(?!#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9]+>)/','',$Value);
$Value = preg_replace('/&(?!#?[a-zA-Z0-9]+;)/','&amp;',$Value);
```

I have now only troubles to fix the > tags, because I'd have to use lookup-behind, which doesn't allow non fixed length RegEx.

```
$Value = preg_replace('/(?<!<[a-zA-Z0-9]+)>/','',$Value);
```

Any ideas?

Greetings
-Thomas

Comment: Oh, no, please not again

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php should help you out.

Comment: htmlspecialchars would replace the tags, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [DOM Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) and apply your replacements to the text nodes only.

```
$partialId = uniqid();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(sprintf('<div id="%s">%s</div>', $partialId, $html));
echo $dom->saveHtml($dom->getElementById($partialId));
```

Just parsing the partial will already turn XML special chars to their respective entities:

```
<div id="4f02efa1a4e9b">this is my fancy <i>text</i> I love my text lalalal &gt; wow I'm great"</div>
```

If you are not on PHP 5.3.6 you cannot use `saveHTML` with a node. See [How to get innerHTML of DOMNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument) and [How to return outer html of DOMDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element/5404962#5404962) for workarounds.

If you need to work on the text nodes, you can do

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//text()') as $textNode) {
    $textNode->nodeValue = doSomething($textNode->nodeValue);
}
```

Also see [DOMDocument in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721) for an introduction to how DOM works.

Comment: Doesn't a DOM Parser need a valid html? I'm usually only getting a text like: "this is my fancy <i>text</i> I love my text lalalal > wow I'm great"

Comment: DOMDocument::loadHTML can load partial HTML. This will add any required HTML skeleton (html, head, body) and you need some coding gymnastics to get the partial out of the DOMDocument with PHP < 5.3.6 but apart from that it works reliably. There is a couple dozen questions on SO asking for individual aspects of this so give it a search when you run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think http://htmlpurifier.org/ can do what you need.

Check out the demo here: http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php to test the options it has.