# DOMDocument outer HTMl

Tags: php, domdocument

**Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element/5404962#5404962) by using `saveHtml` of the particular node.**

---

I am trying to convert a few `spans` into an unordered list. I have to assume that the list items are separated by a `<span ... </span>`

For example, this is some of the html that I need to convert:

```
<span class="FirstClass"> Send the author a PM </span>
<span id="blah"><a href="a_link_here"</a></span>
<span><img src="www...." /></span>
```

I can replicate these into a list, but I don't know how to preserve the hyperlinks and images in each `span`. I can only get the nodeValue and Attributes. I really just need to get everything in between.

This is what I am doing:

```
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span');
$i = 0;
echo '<ul>';
 foreach ($elements as $param) {
  $node = $elements->item($i);
  echo '<li>';
   if ($node->hasAttributes()) {
        echo '<span ';
        foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
        echo $attr->nodeName.'="'.$attr->nodeValue.'"';
   }
     echo '>';
      }
     else
        echo '<span>';
     echo  $node->nodeValue . '</span></li>';
     $i++;
  }
   echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: so you are requesting for src,href and the text content inside the <span> right

Comment: Basically everything inside the span. I found that the solution was to simply use `savehtml`

Comment: ok i have a solution to bring out all content inside the <span> using dom document