# PHP DomNode->insertBefore()

Tags: html, domdocument, php

I am trying to insert nodes in my html string.
My goal is to insert an element before each h2 tag.

For that, I am using:

```
$htmlString = "<h2>some html</h2>";

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlString);

$itemTitles = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('h2');

for($i = 0; $i < $itemTitles->length; $i ++)
{
    $helpNavigatorContents[] = $itemTitles->item($i)->nodeValue;
    $textBefore = new DOMNode(
        '<a name="'.$itemTitles->item($i)->nodeValue.'"></a>'
    );
    $itemTitles->item($i)->parentNode->insertBefore(
        $textBefore, 
        $itemTitles->item($i)
    );
}

$htmlString = $DOM->saveHTML($DOM);
```

And here I have a problem with the `$textBefore`. When I declare the `$textBefore` as a `DOMText`, I can insert the text before the node but when I try this with `DOMNode`, then I am getting the following error ([Demo](https://eval.in/34679)):

> Warning: DOMNode::insertBefore(): Couldn't fetch DOMNode

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code doesn't make any sense. `DOMNode` does not have a constructor. It is not supposed to be created at all. You are supposed to create specific node types through `DOMDocument` to have them associated with the Document.

Assuming you want to prepend all the H2 element with an anchor, this is how to do it:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$DOM = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($htmlString);
$DOM->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

foreach ($DOM->getElementsByTagName('h2') as $h2) {
    $a = $DOM->createElement('a');
    $a->setAttribute('name', $h2->nodeValue);
    $h2->parentNode->insertBefore($a, $h2);
}
$DOM->formatOutput = true;
echo $DOM->saveHTML();
```

Demo http://codepad.org/N0dPcLwT

To wrap the H2 elements into the A element, simply do the same and add

```
$a->appendChild($h2);
```

Demo http://codepad.org/w7Hi0Bmz

Comment: Thank you very much @Gordon, I will try this and as soon I finish, I will let you know if I have some other trubles with.

Comment: It works as a charm @Gordon, the only think I would like to ask you: a new html body is inserted when adding those tags: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>

Comment: @Milos yes, when you use `loadHTML` it will try to fix any broken html and adds a minimal HTML skeleton. This cannot be turned off from PHP although it is possible in libxml. If you are on PHP > 5.3.6 you can use `$DOM->loadHTML($someNode)` to output the OuterHTML of that node. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element/5404962#5404962

Comment: thanks again for your reply. I am using php 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch. When I am saving the html I am using $DOM->saveHTML($DOM);

Comment: @Milos well, like I said, passing a node gives the *OuterHTML*. If you dont want the entire Document, pass a subtree of the document.

Comment: I am afraid I am not able to pass a subtree of the document. Can you give me an example please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Milos well, pass in `$DOM->documentElement`. That's the HTML element. Or `$DOM->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)` for the body element. You get the idea.

Comment: oh yes, right. By passing $DOM->documentElement, now i have <html><body> added, it's better than before.

Comment: @Milos if you want the innerHTML instead, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument