# PHP nodevalue stripping html tags

Tags: php, domdocument, nodevalue

I have seem similar solutions else where but I haven't been able to convert to work with my own code.

I have a function that splits an html string between the paragraph tags and returns in an array.  Code is as follows...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$domx = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $domx->evaluate("//p");
$result = array();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $result[] = '<' . $entry->tagName . '>' . $entry->nodeValue .  '</' . $entry->tagName . '>';
}

return $result;
```

Can someone assist me to remove the nodeValue element from this so it returns the paragraph content with html tags complete?

- The html I am testing against is this: http://adam-makes-websites.com/tests/htmltest/test.html
- A full test of what im doing with the code  (as it stands with the suggestion to use ownerDocument->saveHTML applied) is here: http://adam-makes-websites.com/tests/htmltest/runtest.txt
- The output from the test can be seen here: http://adam-makes-websites.com/tests/htmltest/runtest.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP + DOMDocument: outerHTML for element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `saveHTML` on the `ownerDocument` property:

```
$result[] = $entry->ownerDocument->saveHTML($entry);
```

Comment: @AdamJones - I ran Orangepill's code, and it worked fine with `saveXML`.

Comment: @PédeLeão I was thinking it might be barfing on saveXML if the contents where not well formed. I know valid HTML != valid XML

Comment: save html doesnt improve it either im afraid.  I have added the html to the question now...

Comment: Change your xpath query to `"//p|//ul"` to include the ul's in the result

Comment: I have another small issue it seems.  Its to do with encoding.  Some chrs in the page appear as â instead of ”    Also spaces in some places appear as Â.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$entries = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
$new_dom = new DOMDocument();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $new_dom->appendChild($new_dom->importNode($entry, TRUE));
}
$result = $new_dom->saveHTML()
```

Comment: this returns no content im afraid

Comment: @AdamJones - I just ran it again with no problem.

Comment: Ive just added a link to the html Im using (within a string variable) that has the code run on it if this helps ?

Comment: the ul/li's are not in p tags... that's why they are missing from the results.

Comment: @AdamJones - I just ran it with the HTML that you provided. It works fine.