# How to parsing HTML Content

Tags: php, html-parsing

I want do a web crawler news. I want load content from link *http://vnexpress.net/tin-tuc/ban-doc-viet/xa-hoi/chay-xe-may-theo-taxi-moi-biet-bi-chem-60-000-dong-2865724.html* and i want get all content div with class fck_detail **and keep original tag from it** . How to do this ?

```
    <div class="fck_detail">
    <p class="Normal" style="text-align:justify;">Some texts</p>
    <p class="Normal" style="text-align:justify;">some texts</p>
    <p class="Normal" style="text-align:justify;">Some texts</p>
    <p class="Normal" style="text-align:justify;">Some texts</p>
    </div>
```

I tried but not success

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile("http://example.com/some.html");
    $selector = new DOMXpath($doc);   
    $node = $selector->query('//div[@class="fck_detail"]')->item(0);
    echo trim($node->nodeValue);
```

The above code gives me the plain text stripped from all HTML only. But I want to keep the HTML.

Comment: I would recommend http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/, it is very easy and looks like jQuery

Comment: @guiligan it's also slow and memory hungry. Besides, if you want something that really looks like jQuery, you have to use phpQuery. Or even better install ext/v8 and then run jQuery in PHP because everyone knows you can never have enough jQuery … not!

Comment: In case you want the outerHTML instead of the innerHTML see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element